# Insert field in document if it don't exist or update it with Mongoose JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, conditional-statements, aggregation

I'm looking to make an endpoint that would change the state of a boolean, but set it to true if the field in the document don't exist.

Here is what I have :

```
let updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, [
    {
      $set: {
        is_blacklisted : {
          $eq: [
            false, "$is_blacklisted"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

This work fine, if the user have the field "is_blacklisted" it will set it to the opposite, but if the field don't exist, nothing happen.

I would like to know if there is a way to set it with a default value if the field don't exist.

I know I could do a first find and check if the field exist but I want to know if there is an alternative / better way to do it with only one request ?

Answer (score 0):

Invert the match:

```
{$set:{
    isBlacklisted: {$ne: [true, "$is_blacklisted"]}
}}
```

If the value is true, it will be changed to false, if the field doesn't exist or the field holds any value other than `true` it will be set to false.

Comment: Mhhh I see but why this would set the field to false if do not exist ? why $eq do not create the field if it do not exist ?

Comment: If the fields doesn't exist, that will set it to true, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/qc2qauqhQ3Y